# Apache not handling files correctly (Handler Help)

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to set up my .htaccess file correctly and I'm having an issue.

The only thing my .htaccess file at the moment is:

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm

This is included because my server is not parsing php in my html files.

However when this is included in my .htaccess file, when I open a page in my browser, the user is prompted to save or open the file locally.

I believe the answer to my issues is setting up an action to be done (run with php) however I cannot find out the path to my php files.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the configuration for enabled modules. On a Debian/Ubuntu type system this will be in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled The file you are looking for is php5.conf

So far all you have done is specify that (dot) htm, html or php files should be served -by default- as application/x-httpd-php, and to my knowledge there is not a single web browser that would attempt to interpret such content -- hence the save-as dialog.

Either you could fix your .htaccess file not to be broken (it is broken behaviour to serve html files as application/x-httpd-php), or you could manually output the correct HTTP headers using the PHP header() function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, everyone seems to love abusing `AddType` (and then complain e.g. that MultiViews is broken). See [this article](http://www.devside.net/articles/php), please.

Comment: I laught. The gay says how people should configure their server, even pretending that php.net is wrong, but first of all, he explains how to configure a server under windows --> fail.

Comment: @Aif you're an idiot then. He explains it under Windows because the wrong instructions are given in the Windows distribution (see the "win32" in http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/win32/install.txt?revision=298625&view=markup ). In fairness, the document now also contains correct configuration, however, the wrong one is still given. And why does explaining how to configure a server under windows evokes a stupid Internet meme anyway?

Comment: there was some sarcasm. sorry about that, let's say bad day. There are actually interesting things in this document.

Answer (score -1):

This is not supposed to work in all cases. It depends on the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive of the web server.

You shoud specify the AddType in the serveur config file rather than in the htaccess.

Comment: His `AddType` is working, otherwise the client wouldn't be receiving a content-type of `application/x-httpd-php` (which it cannot handle and therefore presents the download box). But anyway, he shouldn't be using `AddType`.

Comment: where have you read that the client receives a content type of application/x-httpd-php?

Comment: `when this is included in my .htaccess file, when I open a page in my browser, the user is prompted to save or open the file locally.` – it's the most likely explanation; the alternative being PHP is handling the request but sending another content type explicitly.

Comment: I have already add this issue, but the server prompted me to save the file, beeing the actual source. (so the addtype didn't work in my case).